# What values to return for S_OK or E_FAIL from c# .net code?

Tags: c#, .net, com, return-value

I'm implementing a COM interface that should return int values either `S_OK` or `E_FAIL`. I'm ok returning `S_OK` as I get that back from another call (Marshal.QueryInterface), but if I want to return a failure value what actual value do I use for `E_FAIL`?

(It's such a basic fundamental question that it's hard to find an answer to)

Assuming it's a specific number defined in the Win32 API, is there way to use it within .net code without declaring my own constant?

thanks!

**Update (answered below):**

Maybe I'm being a complete plonker, but I'm having problems with this. According to my Platform SDK, `HRESULT` is a `LONG`, which is a 32-bit signed integer, right? So possible values –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. But 0x80004005 = 2,147,500,037 which is > 2,147,483,647. What gives!?

This means when I try to put this in my code:

```
const int E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
```

I get a compiler error *Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'*.

**Update 2:**

I'm going to declare it like this:

```
const int E_FAIL = -2147467259;
```

because if I try to do something like this:

```
const UInt32 E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
return (Int32)E_FAIL;
```

I get a compiler error *Constant value '2147500037' cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)*

Phew! Who knew how tricky it would be to declare a standard return value.... Somewhere there must be a class lurking that I should have used like **return Win32ReturnCodes.E_FAIL;**  ... *sigh*

**ULTIMATE SOLUTION:**

I now do this by getting the (massive but very useful) HRESULT enum from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HRESULT.html) and adding it to my solution. Then use it something like this:

```
return HRESULT.S_OK;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

E_FAIL is Hex 80004005 in WinError.h

You can see the full [Common HRESULT Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx). You don't have to install C++ just to see the values.

**UPDATE:**

The signed and unsigned versions of 0x80004005 are just two representations of the same bit mask. If you're getting a casting error then use the negative signed value. When casted to an UN signed long it will be the "correct" value. Test this yourself in C#, it'll work
e.g.

This code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UInt32 us = 0x80004005;
        Int32 s = (Int32)us;

        Console.WriteLine("Unsigned {0}", us);
        Console.WriteLine("Signed {0}", s);
        Console.WriteLine("Signed as unsigned {0}", (UInt32)s);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

will produce this output

- Unsigned 2147500037
- Signed -2147467259
- Signed as unsigned 2147500037

So it's safe to use -2147467259 for the value of E_FAIL

Comment: Link died, see the [Common HRESULT Values here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I updated the link for `winerror.h`, there are lots of references out there, just in case the link breaks again a very simple search will get it (also if you've an C++ compiler on your machine there will be a probably be a WinError.h file there)

Answer (score 7):

From WinError.h for Win32

```
#define E_FAIL _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80004005L)
```

To find answers like this, use visual studio's file search to search the header files in the VC Include directory of your visual studio install directory.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the "unchecked" keyword to do this.

e.g.

```
const int E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
```

Answer (score 3):

[VSConstants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.aspx) might do you want you want:

VSConstants.S_OK Field

Generic HRESULT for success.

Namespace:  Microsoft.VisualStudio

Assembly:  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0 (in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.dll)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this:

```
const int EFail = int.MinValue + 0x00004005;
```

to compromise between readability (if you're used to the hex codes) and C#'s restriction.

Answer (score -1):

You should download the platform SDK ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en))

I searched through the code and found the following in winerror.h

```
typedef long HRESULT;

#ifdef RC_INVOKED
#define _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(_sc) _sc
#else // RC_INVOKED
#define _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(_sc) ((HRESULT)_sc)
#endif // RC_INVOKED

#define E_FAIL _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80004005L)
#define S_OK  ((HRESULT)0x00000000L)
```

You should return E_FAIL instead of the value. Simply include winerror.h.

Comment: He has tagged his post C#, therefore he cannot include it and needs to define it himself, thus the question. This is very common in COM and PInvoke'ing.